# Why RNN need two bias vectors?

Tags: pytorch

In [pytorch RNN implementation](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html?highlight=rnn#torch.nn.RNN), there are two biases, `b_ih` and `b_hh`.
Why is this? Is it different from using one bias? If yes, how? Will it affect performance or efficiency?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The formular in [Pytorch Document](http://pytorch.org/docs/master/_modules/torch/nn/modules/rnn.html#RNN) in RNN is self-explained. That is `b_ih` and `b_hh` in the equation.

[image: rnn]

You may think that `b_ih` is bias for input (which pair with `w_ih`, weight for input) and `b_hh` is bias for hidden (pair with `w_hh`, weight for hidden)

Comment: For more context, no; you don't need two. But for historical reasons, there are two.

Answer (score 4):

Actually, the previous (accepted) answer is wrong. The second bias parameter is required only due to compatibility with CuDNN. See same [code documentation](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/_modules/torch/nn/modules/rnn.html#RNNBase):

```py
class RNNBase(Module):
    ...
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...
        w_ih = Parameter(torch.empty((gate_size, layer_input_size), **factory_kwargs))
        w_hh = Parameter(torch.empty((gate_size, real_hidden_size), **factory_kwargs))
        b_ih = Parameter(torch.empty(gate_size, **factory_kwargs))
        # Second bias vector included for CuDNN compatibility. Only one   <---  this
        # bias vector is needed in standard definition.                   <--- comment
        b_hh = Parameter(torch.empty(gate_size, **factory_kwargs))
        ...
```

Comment: But the obvious [follow-up question: Why does CuDNN wants to have two bias parameters?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76051800/why-does-the-cudnn-lstm-requires-two-biases-b-ih-and-b-hh)