# Why does the CuDNN LSTM requires two biases b_ih and b_hh

Tags: lstm, cudnn

The question was asked quite often for the higher-level frameworks:

- [PyTorch: Why RNN need two bias vectors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45005163/why-rnn-need-two-bias-vectors)
- [PyTorch: Why RNN needs two biases?](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/why-rnn-needs-two-biases/557)
- [TF/Keras: Why CuDNNLSTM has more parameters than LSTM?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60353094/why-cudnnlstm-has-more-parameres-than-lstm-in-keras)

The answer is always: Because CuDNN does it that way.

But why is that? Is there a technical reason, some advantage in having this?

Currently I just see multiple disadvantages:

- It is more complicated (one more param, needs more code).
- It is slower (needs extra computation).
- It takes more memory.

Was that just an oversight by the CuDNN developers?

I also wonder (I did not verify): Do those two bias terms get the same gradient, or different gradients? In terms of mathematics, they must get the same gradient. If they do not, it would be incorrect. But I could imagine that this is maybe how they implemented it, that b_hh only gets the grad from the recurrent part, and b_ih only the grad from the feedforward part.

If they do get the same gradients, if you initialize them the same, they should always stay exactly the same (I also did not verify this).

If this is the case, it would be equivalent to using `2 * b` which just a single bias `b`. Note that there is still a small difference to using just `b` instead of `2 * b` in terms of scaling.

There is also `cudnnRNNBiasMode_t`. But I don't really understand the difference of `CUDNN_RNN_SINGLE_INP_BIAS` to `CUDNN_RNN_SINGLE_REC_BIAS`. There should not be any difference, otherwise it would be mathematical incorrect.